# sqlite rand() unique _id return sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

How can i get a predifined(users choise) number of rows from my database and ensure that i display them only once? If use rand() limit 1, and return the cursor the same _id may return twice or more.
I use this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.query("THESIS Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     return cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s) FROM table_name
```

**distinct** world will return unique output it will not give you repeated data

Comment: i do not have duplicate entries to do what u said. Everytime the query runs(onclick) and randomise the table it may occur that the same _ids return. I dont want to do that

Comment: okey got it..

you can store _ids in an array which you got selected.

and again check that is found in array it means do not display data 

and call random() again...